# Any way to have a while loop with multiple variables to fulfill

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to make a simple combat system for a game it the simple type what you want to do and damage happens.

So currently I'm trying to figure if I can have the while loop end after 1 of the 2 different variables are fulfills.

Such as the loop needs to end after either the players health or the monsters health becomes 0 or less.

I quickly threw together a if-else statement but it doesn't seem to be working. I currently don't have a sample code as I wanted to see if I could find how to do it before making the full code. Why get everything for a house before your sure you can make the foundation?

Answer (score 3):

So, you're looking for the `and` operator on these two values. If the lower limit is `0` you can use the falseness of `0` to shorten your condition to:

```
while player_health and monster_health:
```

if they can reach a negative value, you'll need to use `> 0` in conjunction with `and` to check for positive values for these names:

```
while player_health > 0 and monster_health > 0:
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works for the either or system I wanted. it looks like it needs both variables before it can end but I think I can work around that. EDIT: OK I see what you mean. thanks!